# Google Services battery drain on Galaxy devices

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, google-play-services

Here are screenshots from my three Samsung Galaxy devices:

[image: Samsung Galaxy S3] [image: Samsung Galaxy S4]
<sup>Samsung Galaxy S3 (left) and Samsung Galaxy S4 (right; click images for larger variants)</sup>

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014]
<sup>Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 (click image to enlarge)</sup>

It seems, that in each case Google Play Services ("Usługi Google") are mostly responsible for fast battery drain. 2014 lasts only a day now (compared to 3+ days of previous version of 10.1). S4 lasts less than 24 hours, S3 toughly reaches 24 hours.

What is the cause of so fast battery drain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the drain caused by google play services, install the Xposed framework and the module Wakelock Terminator. The free version lets you block 1 app, and that's all you need. Open up Wakelock Terminator, choose to block Google Play services, and filter it with the following: NlpCollectorWakeLock NlpWakeLock CheckinService NetworkLocationLocator. Of course, your device must be rooted. If it isnt, try disabling location access when you're not using it

Comment: Actually what helped most was disabling Google Now *along* with the localization services. Now Note is one day on battery with 89% still left. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem. It started when I accidentally played mp3 through Google Music ("Muzyka Play" in Polish version).

The fix was to clear any cache and data in settings, app manager Google music ("Muzyka Google Play").

Now it stays quiet again and I'm not gonna use it :)