# Google Play services using up battery - Why and how to fix it?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, battery-life, google-play-services, battery-history

Why would Android devices have ***Google Play services*** using up the second-most amount of battery usage over a 24 hour period (second only to screen power)?

On one device, I see ***Google Play services*** using 28% of battery usage.  No updates were performed on that device since the last reboot.

When selecting Settings > Battery > Google Play Services,
 under "Included Packages" it only lists Google Backup Transport, Google Bookmarks Sync, Google Play services, Google Account Manager, Google Contacts Sync, and Google Services Framework. There is almost no data on the device, so nothing is being backed up in the background.

What is causing this, and what can be done to prevent it?

Comment: `What can be causing this, and what can be done to prevent it?` -- Here, have a reason http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks Its not orphan here I guess but it explains the issue.

Comment: This issue has been dealt by a user in the answer here. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68399/google-services-battery-drain-on-galaxy-devices

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the 2 links.  One link is specific to Galaxy devices, which does not apply here (but is still useful reading, so thank you).  The other link is an excellent reference for wakelocks, and thank you for that as well.  I'll read through it carefully.  Given that this question is about a specific service, I think I'll leave this question up, as there might be a specific answer for this service.  If the tips provided in the links you generously provided solve the issue, I'll update things here for everyone. Thanks again!  In the meantime, hopefully someone has a specific answer.

Comment: Did you look to see what background services are running through `Google Play Services`? Your dilemma all depends on what apps that are running that are dependent on that service. Could be a notification or sync/update service.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN How do you see what background services are running through Google Play Services?

Comment: **`settings>battery>`** then tap on Google play services

Comment: Edit your question with a screenshot, please